# package.json usage outside npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I understand that the package.json file is used as a manifest for an application, listing meta-data, dependancies, etc. I know that it can be created via `npm init`. However;

Does it have any use outside a npm environment, do other frameworks use it?

Are there any standards or best-practice policies for usage outside npm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some software can keep custom config in `package.json` using keys that are not used by `npm` to avoid putting a lot of config files in the project.

For example see Babel - it can read configuration stored in `package.json` instead of the usual `.babelrc` file:

- https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#use-via-package-json

You can add Babel config with `package.json` like:

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "babel": {
    // my babel config here
  }
}
```

So it's only for `npm` but of course the main usage is configuring project's dependencies that are (usually) resolved by npm but don't have to - e.g. you can use alternative package managers like yarn:

- https://yarnpkg.com/

Take a look at some projects that considered using package.json for their config but decided not to do so, like e.g. Heroku. See the discussion in this issue:

- https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample/issues/72 (Why package.json and app.json?)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what your end goal is, but the package.json file is only typically used by npm/node. If you wanted your package.json to be the file that automated a bunch of other things you could look at running a few [custom npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts), but be careful that you're not mixing your concerns. Typically you should use the documented standards of the environments you're working in.